# How to eliminate stack trace when running Specs through SBT?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs, sbt

I have a Scala project that I'm using SBT and Specs on. When I run sbt test, it correctly runs my tests, but a failing test results in a huge stack trace.

```
[info] 
== caravan.DependenciesSpec ==
[info]   specifies 
[info]   x Status should mirror single job
org.specs.specification.FailureExceptionWithResult: 'caravan.Status(2)' is not equal to 'caravan.Status(3)'
    at caravan.DependenciesSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(DependenciesSpec.scala:13)
...about 70 lines of stack trace though specs...
[error]   org.specs.specification.FailureExceptionWithResult: 'caravan.Status(2)' is not equal to 'caravan.Status(3)'
```

What I would expect is that it just reports the test failed. I'm running specs 1.6.0 and SBT 0.5.5 with Scala 2.7.5. My specs are written as:

```
object DependenciesSpec extends Specification {
...
```

Is there any way to get usable output out of Specs/SBT?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that the new xsbt launcher 0.6.10 added a `trace on|off|<n>` command to control stack trace outputs. See this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/591548358d282319#) on the sbt google group for release announcement and the [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/detail?id=58).

Apparently it will depend on whether `Specs` sends the stack trace to `sbt` too.

Comment: Will require Specs 1.6.2 which contains a fix for launching Specs test from sbt. See http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/ChangeLog.